# Relation between girth and induced subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

In the book, Introduction to Graph Theory by Douglas West, section 1.3.10 has an example on Petersen Graph. There is a statement in the example which states "***Since G has girth 5, every 6 cycle F is an induced subgraph***". I have understood that girth of Petersen graph is 5, and that it has ten 6 cycles... but have not understood the sentence in bold and italics.In the book, I could not find any relation between girth and sub-graph.  I would request for some easy explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Take any $6$-cycle in the Petersen graph with vertices $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_6$. Aside from the six edges $(v_1, v_2), (v_2, v_3), \dots, (v_6,v_1)$ forming the cycle, no other edges $(v_i, v_j)$ can be present, because then they'd form two cycles, at least one of which would be shorter than $5$.

(For example, if the edge $(v_4, v_6)$ were present, then we'd get a $5$-cycle formed by $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_6$, which is possible, and a $3$ cycle formed by $v_4, v_5, v_6$, which is not possible. This is directly related to girth: the Petersen graph has girth $5$, meaning it contains no cycles shorter than $5$-cycles.)

In other words, if we take the subgraph of the Petersen graph induced by the vertices $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_6\}$, that subgraph must be isomorphic to $C_6$, because it contains no edges other than the ones that form the cycle.